# dplyr mutate on dataframe .Label value, not reference

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
temp <- structure(list(ID = c("1234", "1223", "5555", "2344", "4567", "6543"), 
       Eat = structure(c(6L,1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
       .Label = c("", "Cabbage", "Carrot", "Lettuce", "Potato","Asparagus", "Mushroom", "Apple"), class = "factor")), 
      row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ID", "Eat"))
```

I want to note each time there is nothing to Eat:

```
temp %>% mutate(Eat = ifelse(Eat != "" & !is.na(Eat), Eat, "Nothing!"))
```

However, the result is the mutate on the Eat structure values,:

```
    ID      Eat
1 1234        6
2 1223 Nothing!
3 5555        5
4 2344        2
5 4567        3
6 6543        4
```

How can I get the .Labels carried across to make:

```
    ID      Eat
1 1234Asparagus
2 1223 Nothing!
3 5555   Potato
4 2344  Cabbage
5 4567   Carrot
6 6543  Lettuce
```

Comment: `str(temp)` shows that column `eat` is a factor with 8 levels. One level is `""`.  I would try to change the name of that level.

Comment: this is part of a larger problem that I've tried to make manageable for SO, it's not that simple I'm afraid. Thanks though!

Comment: Hadley has written `forcats::fct_recode` for the purpose: `library(forcats) ; temp %>% mutate(Eat = fct_recode(Eat, 'Nothing!' = ''))`

Comment: Is it required to use `factor` in your project? `character` are much easier to handle. I only use `factor` whne it comes to plotting.

Comment: I could re-code the dataframe, it's much much larger than shown (1m+), this is just an example. Wouldn't character make it eat up more memory?

Comment: No, characters are  stored very efficiently.

Comment: dput(temp %>% mutate(Eat = ifelse(Eat != "" & !is.na(Eat), as.character(Eat), "Nothing!"))) does the trick. I take it the implementation of character is different from the dput output!

Comment: @UweBlock do you want to add your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not an requirement in your project, try to avoid `factor`. `character` are much easier to handle and are stored as memory efficient as `factor`. I only use factor when it comes to plotting or some specific sort order other than alphabetical is needed.

> ["... R has a global string pool. This means that each unique string is only stored in one place, and therefore character vectors take up less memory than you might expect" (Hadley Wickham, Advanced R)](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

This was different in the past which explains why coercion of strings to `factor` was and still is the default in many functions. You have to call `read.csv` or `data.frame` with the explicit parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid this.

Recent R packages like `data.table` or those from Hadley's *tidyverse* (`tibble`) never coerce inputs.

But if you need `factor` you may follow @Alistaire's advice and use Hadley's `forecats` package.

Answer (score 2):

The tidyverse way of changing a factor level is `forcats::fct_recode`, which maintains the factor type but changes any specified levels:

```
library(forcats)

temp %>% mutate(Eat = fct_recode(Eat, 'Nothing!' = ''))

##     ID       Eat
## 1 1234 Asparagus
## 2 1223  Nothing!
## 3 5555    Potato
## 4 2344   Cabbage
## 5 4567    Carrot
## 6 6543   Lettuce
```